# Is it possible to suppress mypy's "Expected TypedDict key to be string literal" warning?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm integrating mypy into an existing code base with a few instances of code of this kind:

```
def foo(bar: str) -> Dict[str, QuuxType]:
    # do stuff
    return {
        bar: some_quuxtype_value,
    }
```

Note that the key in the returned `dict` is set to the input variable (this seems like a bit of a code smell, I know, but given the option I'll try to tackle that later).

Running `mypy` over this section of code yields a warning:

> Expected TypedDict key to be string literal

Is there an option to disable this warning? I can't find much mention of it after a quick scan of [the `mypy` config docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html).

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. This code works fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

Although you haven't given enough context, I will assume that you are trying to access the key of a TypedDict with a variable instead of a string.

In the following example I have one example where accessing a key with a string literal works, and another where it will fail (but the error is suppressed).

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    fruit: str
    veggie: str

foo_instance: Foo = {'fruit': 'apple', 'veggie': 'carrot'}
print(foo_instance['fruit']) # will work

# will error unless ignored
for key in foo_instance.keys():
    print(foo_instance[key]) # type: ignore
```

See this mypy playground: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=3513b1411b6795fb2299cf8c0e451b3f

This quirk is discussed on [Github](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7178):

> We don't support that, no. I think it does work if key is given a
>   Literal type, but that doesn't seem super useful.
>
> The dynamic version we definitely won't be able to do useful
>   typechecking of, I think. Best move is probably a # type: ignore